# How can I make each individual graph bigger when using facet_wrap in the ggplot2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code producing my graph:

```
county_br_saleyear_graph <- ggplot(county_br_saleyear_df) + 
    geom_bar(aes(x = br, y = avg_house_price_by_year, color = county), stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(county~sale_year, shrink = FALSE)
county_br_saleyear_graph
```

And the resulting graph:

[image]

How can I make this more presentable?

Comment: This is the result of the size of your window plot, when you import with the ideal dimensions it will be ok. You can also use the command x11() vefore the plot to have a larger window.

Comment: As written, this is a not so great question. The question is really broad, and it would help to have some specific points you would like to improve. Also, we can't help you with any code, because we can't reproduce the figure without data.

Comment: Export as a larger image (`ggsave(plot, height =20, width =20)`)

Comment: Place the legend in the bottom & make it horizontal w/ 2 or 3 rows